# How to sort a Pandas DataFrame using values not in any of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with several columns, one of which contains full names. I want to sort the DataFrame based on the last names.

I have a function `get_last` that extracts the last name from a full name. I know that I can just create a new column that contains the last names, sort based on that column, and then drop it, something like

```py
df['last_name'] = df['name'].apply(get_last)
df = df.sort_values('last_name').drop('last_name', axis=1)
```

but this doesn't seem like a very elegant or efficient solution.

If I was just sorting a list of full names by last name, I could just do

```py
names = sorted(names, key=get_last)
```

but that doesn't work with a DataFrame.

Is there a better way to do this, or should I just stick with my current solution?

Answer (score 1):

We can using `argsort`

```
df=df.iloc[df['name'].apply(get_last).argsort()]
```